# Correlations - multiple observations & multiple observers

Tags: regression, correlation, reliability, psychometrics, nested-data

[image]I haven't found quite this question on here.

I have a data set that typically requires generalizability theory to untangle however I now face a question I believe g theory can not answer.

17 participants answered 1 question.
approx. 8-20 raters from rating source X rated each answer
approx. 6 raters from rating source Y rated each answer

I would like to answer the question "does rating source matter?"
specifically, if i were a participant, would my rank order change depending on who rated my answer? (not looking at stringency between rating source).

This would be a basic correlation where a negative correlation means - it does matter who rated your answer because your rank order would change depending.

However,
I do not want to aggregate the multiple observations as they are, for the most part, all different raters (this would cause problems with randomization? and other things?)

I also don't want to leave them and exaggerate the df.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you are interested in both, how (dis)similar the questions and how (dis)similar the sources about those questions are. If so, you can have a look at the [Multitrait-Multimethod-Matrix](https://socialresearchmethods.net/kb/mtmmmat.php) (MTMM) approach where one assumes that some part of the variance is due to shared method (in your case due to same source/ rater) and also due to the same thing (trait) being measured (in your case the question). After a quick look I saw that yo can perform [analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitrait-multimethod_matrix) for MTMM, but I am not familiar with that.

Otherwise, if your main interest is whether it matters by which rater group someone is rated you can use one of the group tests for central tendency, like the t test, the welch test or the Mann-Whitney test, depending on your data. Or, if your data is paired, meaning that each answer was rated by both rate groups, you would use the dependent t test or a Wilcoxon test, again depending on your data..

EDIT

Does your data look like this?

```
user.    Rating A.    Rating B

1        6             4

2        8             6

3        5             2

...      ...           ...
```

Where Rating A and Rating B are the two different institutions. If your data does look like this then you have repeated measures with 2 observations per user and if you want to know whether the score are different depending on what Rater has rated them you can use a dependent t test or a Wilcoxon test. Unless I still misunderstand your design.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am not interested in the construct validity of the questions (I am actually only looking at 2 questions as this is not my primary focus).  More standard significance tests like a t test (and non parametric versions you mentioned) would for the most part give differences in terms of stringency.  The only test on this list that may work is the Wilcoxon or other rank test and they are testing for ranking change (+ or -).

Comment: However this does not get at the problem of having multiple observations (ratings) per response - are you suggesting I aggregate these ratings even though they are from all different raters and not randomized?

Comment: @APsy: I am afraid I don't fully understand your study design.

Comment: 17 users answered a question.  To score how they performed on that question faculty from 2 different schools rated each answer.  Each individual answer had approx. 8 faculty scoring it.  I want to know if it matters which institution scores the answer. Specifically would the 17 participants rank the same no matter which institution scored it.  The problem is if i were to run a correlation/t test/etc. I have multiple observations per user (as multiple faculty rated each answer).

Comment: @APsy: see the edit of my answer.

Comment: I added an example data set to the original post.  each user has multiple ratings per institution.  I am hesitant to aggregate and run a simple analysis as they are all different raters rating each user.

Comment: @APSY: As I said, obviously I don't understand something. I don't know what "aggregate" means here and why there are many rows for each user (I thought there was only one question). Anyway, someone else might be able to help :) Good luck!

Comment: Say you took a test with one question. your performance on that one item was rated by 8 different people from one institution and 8 different people from another institution. multiple people scoring 1 item.  In this case aggregate is to take an average of all ratings for 1 item to represent how they performed overall. Instead of 1 teacher scoring a test, 8 are scoring the test. Thank you for your help! much appreciated. it is good to talk about